# Javascript include conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am simply trying to show 3 diagrams, nothing more. The problem I am encountering is that the whole page turns white when I include the javascript files that belongs to the diagram number 2 and 3. How can I prevent this conflict, any ideas?

**Error code I receive in console:**

- uncaught exception: Highcharts error #16:
  www.highcharts.com/errors/16
- SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
- ExhaustTemperature.js $(...).highcharts is not a function

Here is the library for diagram 1.

```
<script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>
```

Here is the library for diagram 2 and 3.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Then the funny part... The whole page turns white when I include these two javascript files.

```
<script src="diagram2.js"></script>
<script src="diagram3.js"></script>
```

This is what it looks like in index.html file.

```
 <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script src="diagram2.js"></script>
<script src="diagram3.js"></script>
```

Comment: *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'.* That's usually the sign that your server is replying with an error page (in HTML) when serving one of your scripts. Use Fiddler or similar to see the actual response.

Comment: Can you post here the js files that you are including please? We cant help you when you provide code like this.

Comment: The first error is because you are including the **`highstock.js`** too many times. It should be included only once.

Comment: Yes, the dilemma is that diagram 1 uses highchart.js (modified), while diagram 2 and 3 uses the library highstock.js via http link. @RaeenHashemi

Comment: Your modified version and the original version of the js file shouldn't intersect. Maybe you should exclude the part in your modified js where the two files have the same code (only include the changed code). But either way there is no way for the charts to know which js to use from, unless you use **`iframes`** for each different chart.

Comment: Well, there's your problem then you have a conflict. You already knew this, re-factor the code to accept only one unique script. The other thing you can do is check the console, this will pin point where the actual errors are, You should post those here too.

Comment: Just to clarify things: Highstock contains Highcharts core. Remove `highcharts.js` script. If you have modified `highcharts.js` then merge changes with `highstock.js`. Remember about proper order of the files.